# И за чего SVG не отображается нормально на iphone?

Tags: svg, svg-filter

Добрый день есть такой код SVG

```html
<svg width="358" height="358" viewBox="0 0 358 358" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g filter="url(#filter0_d)">
<path d="M318 175C318 206.596 307.235 237.25 287.48 261.909C267.724 286.568 240.157 303.76 209.322 310.652C178.486 317.545 146.223 313.726 117.848 299.826C89.474 285.925 66.6821 262.773 53.229 234.183C39.776 205.594 36.4646 173.274 43.8406 142.551C51.2166 111.828 68.8399 84.5341 93.8059 65.1685C118.772 45.8028 149.591 35.5209 181.183 36.0171C212.776 36.5134 243.256 47.7584 267.602 67.8986L179 175H318Z" fill="url(#paint0_linear)"/>
</g>
<defs>
<filter id="filter0_d" x="0" y="0" width="358" height="358" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/>
<feOffset dy="4"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="20"/>
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0.203922 0 0 0 0 0.72549 0 0 0 0 0.788235 0 0 0 1 0"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow" result="shape"/>
</filter>
<linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="179" y1="36" x2="179" y2="314" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="#2197A5"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#3DC8D9"/>
</linearGradient>
</defs>
</svg>
```

На других браузерах включая мобильные все выглядит отлично, а вот на IOS режется. Именно на всех браузерах IOS. Кто может подсказать в чем дело

Comment: некоторые фильтры не кросс браузерные

Comment: @StrangerintheQ SVG код от дизайнера получил, поэтому и под вопросом. Как по мне такие фигуры должны были по другому делаться. Возможно ли с этим что то сделать? ибо они важны... И самое главное такая ошибка не выскакивает в браузерах вроде Ie11, Firefox , Opera  , а именно лишь на IOS ( не важно какой браузер )

Comment: растеризуйте и вставьте картинкой

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Тоже подумал об этом варианте, а вариант с SVG полностью отпадает? Или какие могут быть инструкции для дизайнера что бы он переделывал SVG. Кстати на айфоне тогда 100% и за этого кода такие баги?

Comment: :) сразу проверять на всех платформах

Comment: кстати у меня работает одинаково как в хроме на desktop так и на ios(safari)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> На других браузерах включая мобильные все выглядит отлично, а вот на
>   IOS режется. Именно на всех браузерах IOS. Кто может подсказать в чем
>   дело

Есть две потенциальные ошибки, которые могут не обрабатываться `Safari`

1. В градиенте не задано значение первое значение `stop offset ="0"`

было:

```
<stop stop-color="#2197A5"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#3DC8D9"/>
```

изменить на:

```
<stop offset="0" stop-color="#2197A5"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#3DC8D9"/>
```

2. В фильтре `feColorMatrix` указано ошибочное значение `127` непрозрачности, которое не может быть больше `1`

Было:

```
<feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/>
```

Изменить на:

```
<feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"/>
```

Попробуйте, измененный код, мне к сожалению не на чем проверить.

```html
<svg width="358" height="358" viewBox="0 0 358 358" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g filter="url(#filter0_d)">
<path d="M318 175C318 206.596 307.235 237.25 287.48 261.909C267.724 286.568 240.157 303.76 209.322 310.652C178.486 317.545 146.223 313.726 117.848 299.826C89.474 285.925 66.6821 262.773 53.229 234.183C39.776 205.594 36.4646 173.274 43.8406 142.551C51.2166 111.828 68.8399 84.5341 93.8059 65.1685C118.772 45.8028 149.591 35.5209 181.183 36.0171C212.776 36.5134 243.256 47.7584 267.602 67.8986L179 175H318Z" fill="url(#paint0_linear)"/>
</g>
<defs>
<filter id="filter0_d" x="0" y="0" width="358" height="358" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"/>
<feOffset dy="4"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="20"/>
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0.203922 0 0 0 0 0.72549 0 0 0 0 0.788235 0 0 0 1 0"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow" result="shape"/>
</filter>
<linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="179" y1="36" x2="179" y2="314" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop offset="0" stop-color="#2197A5"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#3DC8D9"/>
</linearGradient>
</defs>
</svg>
```

**Update**

3. **Наиболее вероятной причиной обрезания изображения может быть** [Filter effects region](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html#FilterEffectsRegion) (зона действия фильтра)
   При недостаточной ширине или высоте зоны действия фильтра изображение может быть обрезано. Попробуйте увеличить атрибуты `width`, `height` и/или подвинуть верхний угол региона `x`, `y`

`<filter id="filter0_d" x="0" y="0" width="358" height="358"`

Для примера, я сделаю меньше зону действия фильтра `358 -> 300` и изображение обрежется:

```html
<svg width="358" height="358" viewBox="0 0 358 358" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g filter="url(#filter0_d)">
<path d="M318 175C318 206.596 307.235 237.25 287.48 261.909C267.724 286.568 240.157 303.76 209.322 310.652C178.486 317.545 146.223 313.726 117.848 299.826C89.474 285.925 66.6821 262.773 53.229 234.183C39.776 205.594 36.4646 173.274 43.8406 142.551C51.2166 111.828 68.8399 84.5341 93.8059 65.1685C118.772 45.8028 149.591 35.5209 181.183 36.0171C212.776 36.5134 243.256 47.7584 267.602 67.8986L179 175H318Z" fill="url(#paint0_linear)"/>
</g>
<defs>
<filter id="filter0_d" x="0" y="0" width="300" height="300" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/>
<feOffset dy="4"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="20"/>
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0.203922 0 0 0 0 0.72549 0 0 0 0 0.788235 0 0 0 1 0"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow" result="shape"/>
</filter>
<linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="179" y1="36" x2="179" y2="314" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="#2197A5"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#3DC8D9"/>
</linearGradient>
</defs>
</svg>
```

**Update2** по комментарию

> Да действительно причиной была 3 пункт. На адаптиве я уменьшал размеры
>   svg путем css, но значения width и height для filter оставались
>   неизменными, пришлось задать и для них изменения.

Лучше задавать filter region в процентах `width="120%" height="120%" x="-20%" y="-20%"` (Эти значения по умолчанию)  `filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"` - в этом случае указывать нельзя (просто удалите)

Comment: @alexandr-tt Да действительно причиной была 3 пункт. На адаптиве я уменьшал размеры svg путем css, но значения width и height для filter оставались неизменными, пришлось задать и для них изменения. Огромное вам спасибо

Comment: @Danielqwaqwaqwa поэтому лучше задавать filter region в процентах width="120%" height="120%" x="-20%" y="-20% "  `filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"` в этом случае указывать нельзя' (просто удалите)